# Once an hour, 500 error '/_ah/datastore_admin/mapreduce_done'

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce, google-cloud-datastore

In the request log of Google App Engine (GAE), '/_ah/datastore_admin/mapreduce_done' error appears once an hour.

[GAE application request logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTA1c.png)

As a possibility of error, I think that job of backup from the Google Datastore remains illegally. However, as you can see in the capture below, there was no job left on the Datastore management screen.

[Datastore mgmt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIKP8.png)

Thanking you for your advice.

Comment: Go to the taskqueue section of your GAE admin panel.  Look for a task stuck in the queue.  Also click on the "cron jobs" tab and look for errors there.  You can retry a cron job to check the error.

Comment: anyone having this issue today? (Jan 2021).  I have the same error since 2016. I can't find a running job/task in GAE or Datastore. I've replace the old PHP GAE version with a new empty Python (hello world). But the errors keep showing.